# flickr .net api get frob with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, flickr

I'm using Asp.net MVC and trying to use the flickr api via: http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/

I've looked at the documentation and son't know how to get this to work for MVC. see snippet from docs:

> Web authentication? Different how?
>
> For web based authentication you must specify in the Edit
>   Configuration page of your API key the page to redirect users to after
>   they have authenticated your application. Its called the Callback URL.
>   You also do not need to create a Frob when using web based
>   authentication.
>
> You can use the Flickr.AuthCalcWebUrl method to generate a URL to
>   redirect the user to.
>
> ```
> string url = flickr.AuthCalcWebUrl(AuthLevel.Write);
> Response.Redirect(url);
> ```
>
> Then in the page specified by the Callback URL above you get passed
>   the Frob in the query string. E.g. if your callback URL is
>   http://example.com/flickr.aspx then the user will be redirected to
>   http://example.com/flickr.aspx?frob=1234abcd1234abcd.
>
> Then you can use the Frob to get the authentication token as in the
>   example above:
>
> ```
> protected void Page_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   string frob = Request.QueryString["frob"];
>   Flickr flickr = new Flickr(ApiKey, SharedSecret);
> ```

I have pasted the url returned by the AuthCalcWebUrl into my callbackurl in the settings page of my app.

The question is in MVC how do i do the redirect to then get the frob?

Answer (score 3):

Ive just done this and thought I would let you know how I did it.

In my first view (the one with a button which causes the attempted authorization) I have the standard index method and also one which is for a HTTP post. This runs the code to request authorization if I hit my Authorize button

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Flickr.CacheDisabled = true;
    string secret = "sss";
    string apikey = "abc";
    Flickr myFlickr = new Flickr(apikey, secret);

    var flickrFrob = myFlickr.AuthGetFrob();
    string url = myFlickr.AuthCalcUrl(flickrFrob, AuthLevel.Write);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Then I have another action which takes in the frob.

```
public ActionResult Authenticated(string frob)
{
    Flickr.CacheDisabled = true;
    string secret = "sss";
    string apikey = "abc";

    Flickr flickr = new Flickr(apikey, secret);
    Auth auth = flickr.AuthGetToken(frob);

    ViewData.Add("frob", frob);
    return View();
}
```

This second action is the location of the callback in flickr.

So for example; If this action was in the Home controller the callback would be
    www.mysite.com/Home/Authenticated/

As this action method takes in a string of 'frob' this will be populated with the generated code.

To view this you can just output it from our viewbag or store it wherever you need to etc..